# Binding library error: How to make a method return an array of IDictionary<TKey,TValue>?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I am getting an error when I import a .aar file to integrate with a machine service.

My question is as per the title.

This the code I am trying to get:

```
[Register ("getSlots", "()[Ljava/util/HashMap;", "")]
public unsafe global::System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary<string,byte[]>[] GetSlots()
{
    const string __id = "getSlots.()[Ljava/util/HashMap;";
    try {
        var __rm = _members.InstanceMethods.InvokeNonvirtualObjectMethod (__id, this, null);
        return (global::System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary<string,byte[]>[])
                  JNIEnv.GetArray(__rm.Handle,JniHandleOwnership.TransferLocalRef,
                                  typeof (global::System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary<string,byte[]>));
        }
    finally {
    }
}
```

This is the code I am getting:

```
[Register ("getSlots", "()[Ljava/util/HashMap;", "")]
        public unsafe global::System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary <string, byte[]>GetSlots ()
        {
            const string __id = "getSlots.()[Ljava/util/HashMap;";
            try {
                var __rm = _members.InstanceMethods.InvokeNonvirtualObjectMethod (__id, this, null);
                return (global::System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary<string, byte[]>[]) JNIEnv.GetArray (__rm.Handle, JniHandleOwnership.TransferLocalRef, typeof (global::System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary<string, byte[]>));
            } finally {
            }
        }
```

I need a method that returns an array `IDictionary <string, byte[]>[]`, but I am getting `IDictionary <string, byte[]>`

This is the code that is in metadata.xml

```
<attr path="/api/package[@name='br.com.uol.pagseguro.plugpagservice.wrapper']/class[@name='PlugPagNFCResult']/method[@name='getSlots' and count(parameter)=0]" name="managedReturn">System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary &lt;string, byte[]&gt;</attr>
```

But every time I write "`[]`", after "`>`", it doesn't appear to form an array!

Could you help me with this?

Comment: Please edit your question in english.

Comment: Assuming this is Portuguese, try https://pt.stackoverflow.com/ instead.